# Express.js Server error handling (404). Server freaks out and throws exception before I'm even allowed to handle the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, http-status-code-404

(If it matters, I'm using the Blizzard.js npm package in tandem with Express.)

I'm building a web-app that lets users search for stats of a certain video game 
character (player-created profiles), and since there are a usernames that don't exist, I'm trying to make sure my app can handle it if the user searches for a username that doesn't have an account.

When I query for a non-existent username, instead of letting my server function see and handle it, the server freaks out and throws a few errors in a file that's only called `node.js` (at line 369 who's content is `runMicrotasks();`). I've noticed I have to hit "resume" in my debugger twice. However it doesn't crash the entire server. On the user's side, nothing happens.

However in my server call I make sure to handle anything that's not a 200 by assuming the character doesn't exist and telling that to the user.(I know, lazy. I should only do that if there's a 404 being thrown, but I haven't gotten past this bug). My if-statement is supposed to catch this, but I've set breakpoints on and inside the call and it doesn't even hit my breakpoints. The server call never fires.

Code making the call to my server:

```
$scope.searchCharacter = function(){
    $scope.charName = "obviouslyInvalidCharacterName";
    $scope.selectedRealm = {name: "Dalaran", id: 66};
    var request = {name: $scope.charName, realm: $scope.selectedRealm};    
    $http.post('/searchCharacter', request)
    .then(function(response) {
        //request body
    });
}
```

Server call:

```
app.post('/searchCharacter', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    blizzard.wow.character(['profile', 'stats', 'items', 'statistics'], { origin: 'us', realm: req.body.realm.name, name: req.body.name })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.status != 200){
            res.send("That character doesn't exist! Please enter a valid character name.");
        } else {
            res.send(response.data);
        }
    });
});
```

Error message:

```
Error:
Exception has occurred: Error
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream 12-7-17\Project\node_modules\blizzard.js\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream 12-7-17\Project\node_modules\blizzard.js\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:18:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (c:\Users\RDubz\Documents\Interviews\EagleDream 12-7-17\Project\node_modules\blizzard.js\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:191:11)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:921:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Blizzard, but you have a potential unhandled promise rejection. After the `.then()` do a `.catch(console.log)` to see if there are any rejections of exceptions thrown.

It could be that you aren't paying attention to nuances of the API (or the documentation just isn't good).

For example, in native fetch API error status code does not throw an error/rejection, but maybe in this Blizzard one it does? Just a guess, check it out and see! :)